# What is this eclipse file purple explorer icon?

Tags: c, eclipse, icons, code-composer

Eclipse popped a new one on me this morning. See the circled icon in the image.
I have looked at lots of links from similar posts on SO (though didnt find any for thsi exact icon) and none of the links have mentioned this.

FYI this is in Texas Instruments Code Composer Eclipse "package", or however it's termed, but searching over at TI has been just as fruitless.

[image: Screenshot of eclipse project explorer with mystery icon]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means this folder is in a workspace path.